# Find a sinusoidal regression equation for some given data.

Tags: regression, periodic-functions

I have some data which is sinusoidal when graphed. I want to find a regression equation for these data of the form: $$f_{(x)}=A\sin \left[\frac{2\pi}{B} (x-C)\right]+D$$

I estimated all the constants $A,B,C$ and $D$ from the graph and found a reasonable sinusoidal regression curve for these data, happy days.

But I am wondering whether or not there is some way of plotting my data in a linear form such that the slope and intercept etc. will give me a more accurate estimate for the constants. Is there such a method? What would be the simplest way to go about it?

I am not referring to any specific data sample but would like to know how to go about this in general.

Here are some data though that we can work with.

$$x=(1,2,3,4,5,6)$$ $$y=(3.42,0.73,0.12,2.16,4.97,5.97)$$

My work: $$A=\frac{5.97-0.12}{2}=2.925$$ $$D=0.12+2.925=3.045$$ $$C=\frac{6+3}{2}=4.5$$ $$B=2(6-3)=6$$ $$f_{(x)}=2.925\sin[\frac{\pi}{3}(x-4.5)]+3.045$$

I could only base my constants on the min and max data available. This method isn't much use if you don't have good extremity data and also if the data don't even cover one full oscillation.

What would be a more accurate way of going about this?

Comment: If you post your data (not on a graph, but on numerical table), it should be possible to test an available method. I don't post an answer without checking if the method is convenient  to the particular case considered.

Comment: @JJacquelin. I bet that your method would work !

Comment: Hi Claude ! I bet so, but one can never know.

Comment: @JJacquelin. Hi Jean ! May I suggest you use my small data set to show how works your method ?

Comment: Hi Claude! In fact, my concern is to know how appears the Derek's data : number of points, how they are distributed, how is the scatter.

Comment: Hi all , I have added some data above to work with. Looking forward to your thoughts.

Comment: @Derek. I used your data and obtained a perfect fit. Look at my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the data cover a large range and do not contain much noise and using as a model $$f(x)=a\sin \left(\frac{2\pi}{b} (x-c)\right)+d$$ we can get some estimates using $$f(0)=d-a \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  c}{b}\right)$$ which gives an estimate of $d$.

For the point $x_1$ where $f(x_1)=0$ we have $$x_1=c-\frac{b \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{d}{a}\right)}{2 \pi }$$  which gives an estimate of $c$.

For the point $x_2$ where $f'(x_2)=0$ we have $$x_2=\frac{b}{4}+c$$  which gives an estimate of $b$ and $f(x_2)=a+d$  gives an estimate of $a$.

So, basically looking at the plot of the data, we have, in principle, at least consistent estimates of all parameters. and we can safely start the full nonlinear regression.

However, this would imply solving a tedious equation for $a$. But using the above, we can reduce in a first step to the fit of a single parameter $a$, parameters $b,c,d$ being expressed as functions of $a$ using the above relations. When the optimum $a$ has been found (this can be done using a plot of the sum of squares computed for a few discret values of $a$ until a minumum value is detected),  we can safely start the full nonlinear regression with consistent estimates.

**Edit**

Thinking more about the problem, I suppose that I should write the model as
$$f(x)=a \sin(\alpha x+\beta)+d\qquad \text{with}\qquad \alpha=\frac {2\pi}b\qquad \text{and}\qquad \beta=-\frac {2\pi c}b$$ Expanding the sine $$f(x)=a \cos (\beta ) \sin (\alpha  x)+a \sin (\beta ) \cos (\alpha  x)+d=A\sin (\alpha  x)+B\cos(\alpha  x)+d $$ which is linear if $\alpha$ is given a specific value.

For this value of $\alpha$, use a linear regression to get the best values of parameters $A( \alpha)$,  $B( \alpha)$, $d( \alpha)$ and compute the sum of square of residuals. You will find, by trial and error, a zone where $SSQ( \alpha)$ is minimum. Fo this value $\alpha_*$, go back $$A(\alpha_*)=a \cos(\beta)\qquad B(\alpha_*)=a \sin(\beta)\qquad \implies\qquad a\qquad \text{and} \qquad\beta$$ which themselves lead to $b$ and $c$.

For illustration purposes, I used the following (synthetic) data set
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & f(x) \\
 0.0 & -11.47 \\
 0.5 & -15.62 \\
 1.0 & -18.19 \\
 1.5 & -19.17 \\
 2.0 & -18.02 \\
 2.5 & -15.30 \\
 3.0 & -11.06 \\
 3.5 & -6.34 \\
 4.0 & -1.50 \\
 4.5 & +2.33 \\
 5.0 & +4.92 \\
 5.5 & +5.49 \\
 6.0 & +4.33
\end{array}
\right)$$
Below are reported the results of the linear regressions for different values of $\alpha$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \alpha & \\
 0.1 & \{145.375,\{A\to -7.60697,B\to -174.895,d\to 158.722\}\} \\
 0.2 & \{135.708,\{A\to -5.44567,B\to -48.7632,d\to 32.6894\}\} \\
 0.3 & \{119.635,\{A\to -5.52408,B\to -25.2303,d\to 9.34186\}\} \\
 0.4 & \{97.4249,\{A\to -6.2399,B\to -16.7424,d\to 1.16049\}\} \\
 0.5 & \{69.9893,\{A\to -7.29279,B\to -12.459,d\to -2.63686\}\} \\
 0.6 & \{39.7696,\{A\to -8.58334,B\to -9.62791,d\to -4.7105\}\} \\
 0.7 & \{12.4717,\{A\to -10.0273,B\to -7.20268,d\to -5.97143\}\} \\
 0.8 & \{\color{red}{0.0564199},\{A\to -11.4518,B\to -4.6306,d\to -6.79914\}\} \\
 0.9 & \{24.2511,\{A\to -12.4754,B\to -1.59026,d\to -7.37301\}\} \\
 1.0 & \{115.154,\{A\to -12.4273,B\to 1.90681,d\to -7.78404\}\}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using $\alpha_*=0.8$, we get $a=12.3526$, $d=−6.79914$ and $\beta=-2.75734$ and then $b=7.85398$ and $c=3.44668$. Using these numbers, the reults of the nonlinear regression are 
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 12.346 & 0.0234427 & \{12.2919,12.4001\} \\
 b & 7.89158 & 0.0148157 & \{7.85741,7.92574\} \\
 c & 3.45132 & 0.003368 & \{3.44355,3.45909\} \\
 d & -6.77303 & 0.0209294 & \{-6.82129,-6.72477\} \\
\end{array}$$ As you can notice, the final parameters are quite close to the guesses. Comparing data and prediction
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x & f(x) & \text{prediction} \\
 0.0 & -11.47 & -11.509 \\
 0.5 & -15.62 & -15.558 \\
 1.0 & -18.19 & -18.234 \\
 1.5 & -19.17 & -19.117 \\
 2.0 & -18.02 & -18.070 \\
 2.5 & -15.30 & -15.255 \\
 3.0 & -11.06 & -11.115 \\
 3.5 & -6.34 & -6.2947 \\
 4.0 & -1.50 & -1.5496 \\
 4.5 & +2.33 & +2.3786 \\
 5.0 & +4.92 & +4.8754 \\
 5.5 & +5.49 & +5.5505 \\
 6.0 & +4.33 & +4.2982
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Update**

Using the data you posted in your edit
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & f(x) \\
 1 & 3.42 \\
 2 & 0.73 \\
 3 & 0.12 \\
 4 & 2.16 \\
 5 & 4.97 \\
 6 & 5.97
\end{array}
\right)$$ applying the procedure given in my edit, we obtain
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 3.00141 & 0.00178404 & \{2.97874,3.02408\} \\
 b & 6.28596 & 0.00321329 & \{6.24513,6.32679\} \\
 c & 4.28388 & 0.00094226 & \{4.27190,4.29585\} \\
 d & 2.99993 & 0.00174274 & \{2.97779,3.02207\} \\
\end{array}$$
Comparing data and prediction
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x & f(x) & \text{prediction} \\
 1 & 3.42 &3.42124\\
 2 & 0.73 &0.72783\\
 3 & 0.12 &0.12170\\
 4 & 2.16 &2.15966\\
 5 & 4.97 &4.96954\\
 6 & 5.97 &5.97003
\end{array}
\right)$$ Your very simplified procedure leads to very different results.

Comment: With the method shown pp. 35-36 in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales , for $f(x)=A+B\sin(\omega x)+C\cos(\omega x)$ the result is : $ \omega=0.800386 \:;\: A=-6.801766 \:;\: B=-11.456835 \:;\:C=-4.6199 $

Comment: @JJacquelin. I expected (as usual) that it should work ! Cheers.

Comment: @ Claude : I am surprised that it should work so well. The method with numerical integration is not very efficient in case of low number of points, due to the poor numerical integration.

Comment: @JJacquelin. The problem with democracy is that you have the right of being surprised. My right is to not be !!! I strongly suggest you make an answer for $f(x)=A+B\sin(\omega x)+C\cos(\omega x)$ using your method and, later, transform the parameters to go back to the original. model. Cheers.

Comment: OK. Easy with your notations I found : $a=12.35324 \:;\; b=7.850194 \:;\; c=3.446203 \:;\; d=-6.801766$ This well consistent with your result. No surprise !

Comment: Thanks Claude and JJacquelin , I will need some time to get my head around this method but I trust it's what I'm looking for.